# Setting up Al's R session

Tags: code-golf, programming-puzzle, r

Al wanted to use my computer to do some simple calculations, so I lent him the use of my R terminal for a bit. He complained though, saying it wasn't set up how he liked it. I said "No problem Al, set it up how you like and I'll just revert it later." This suited Al, and I left him to it. Al isn't a big fan of online R implementations like TIO, they don't seem to support his preferred way of coding.

After a few minutes, I came back and asked how it went. "everything fine", he said. I glanced at his session and it didn't look fine to me — only one of the four results looked correct! But Al knows R inside out, he must have been telling the truth.

Here is a transcript of Al's R session, as it appeared on the screen (Al uses RStudio 1.1.463 and R 3.6.3 if it matters, but I don't think it does here). The question is, how did Al "set up" his session to produce this output?

```
## what did Al type here?
‮32+55
[1] 87
‮14*21
[1] 294
‮91/7
[1] 13
‮12-21
[1] -9
```

rules:

- Al only typed one function call which is somewhere in the standard R libraries.
- the function didn't import any code or refer to any external files (no `source`, `install.packages`, `library` etc..).
- Al didn't type `cat("55+23\n[1]......-9")`, it is something that could reasonably be interpreted as "setting up an R session"

scoring:

- the primary scoring criterion is the number of bytes in the answer. Ties will be broken in ASCII-order, that is, if two valid answers are the same length the winner is the one which is first "alphabetically" (according to ASCII ordering).

Comment: I think it belongs to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com rather than here, where whe are supposed to answer with code with a winning criterion?

Comment: Fair enough --- this works as a code-golf, so have changed to that. There are multiple possible answers, I think.

Comment: Before I spoil the answer to other people that know R, does what you have in mind work in TIO? I have tried something but it seems they disabled the support for this in TIO..

Comment: @Kaddath my intended solution doesn't work in TIO, which disables many of the functions you might use to customise your R session. I will add that to the question, though so thanks for trying TIO!

Comment: @Kaddath [tag:programming-puzzle] is on-topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
options(prompt="\U202E")
```

Uses [RTL Override](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/202E) at the end to make all following input appear reversed. I tried entering the raw character in a string but it turns into a period for some reason. Tested with RStudio 1.2.1335 and R 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 20.04, but does not work in my terminal GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 which appears to do some kind of character stripping unless the character is printable. Note that default R prompt is "> " which works in GNOME Terminal and can be replicated to make it less suspicious.

Also Al and R sound like "L" and "R".

Comment: This was the answer I had intended! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","ja")
```

[Try it online! (doesn't work)](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7iyWK84tSQnPzkxJ1VDycc53tHHR0lHKStRSfP/fwA)

I give it a try even if I don't know R and cannot test it on my computer.. If this doesn't work, please tell me and I will delete the answer, because it spoils the trick Al used

Comment: I don't think this would work; it is an attempt to set the locale to Japanese, which could definitely be interpreted as "setting up your R session", but wouldn't explain why the numeric output was the way it was.

Comment: @JDL because it's a right to left language, as I told, I suspected it wouldn't work like this

Comment: I see --- it might work, my own computer refused to change the locale ("Warning message:In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "ja") : OS reports request to set locale to "ja" cannot be honored") so I can't really test it. will see if any other users are able to verify (or otherwise). I hadn't realised Japanese was right-to-left; I thought it was top-to-bottom.

Comment: Don't worry too much that this spoils the "trick" of the question --- it's the more interesting part of the challenge how to achieve this with R's base library anyway (though you could use spoiler tags if you wanted to)

Comment: @JDL yes it's top to bottom, then right to left for the columns. Used this because I found on a SO answer saying that it worked for hebrew (while hebrew locale didn't)

Comment: good to know! then I think this is probably a correct answer, though there are other correct answers with a smaller byte count. Have an upvote! (I certainly learned something today)

Comment: Thanks to you, I made my first steps in R today for your post, was quite a time I heard of it and never gave it a try

Comment: I'm not quite sure it would work, as "On an RTL website the number 500 isn’t written 005, it is still 500" ([source](https://www.locale.to/5-things-you-need-to-know-about-right-to-left-languages/)). Verified the above code on my Windows computer (R 4.0.4) and it doesn't work as desired. *But to be honest, I had the same idea.*

Comment: Yes? But, Japanese (and also Chinese, Korean) is not a RTL language. It does write from right to left if you try to [layout them vertical like this](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/). But the transcript given by OP certainly layout text horizontal instead of vertical.